# Why image is not fit to page screen size?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have placed image (2400x1600) on page, but part of it is cut off:
[image]

image should be fully visible:
[image]

here is my css code:

```
.background-property {
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}
```

would be very grateful if you could explain why it fails and what is the possible solution?

**P.S. HTML code:**

```
 <div class="hero-area-l1  position-relative" style="background: url(image/landing-1/new.png);">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xxl-5 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-10 order-lg-1 order-1" >
            <div class="content">
              <h2>Are you ready</h2>
              <p>With lots of unique blocks, you can easily build a page without coding. Build your next website
                fast.</p>
              <div class="l1-create-acc-btn">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-style-02">Create a free account <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover` ensures that your background image takes up the entire container leaving no empty space...if you want to show the entire image use `background-size: contain`...but it's a tradeoff because you will see edges depending on browser dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest playing around with `background-position: top, bottom, center`. Because your background image seems to be off on the y-axis. I would try `background-position: bottom;`

```css
body {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/52RzfxG/new-1.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: Yellow;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="hero-area-l1  position-relative">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xxl-5 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-10 order-lg-1 order-1" >
            <div class="content">
              <h2>Are you ready</h2>
              <p>With lots of unique blocks, you can easily build a page without coding. Build your next website
                fast.</p>
              <div class="l1-create-acc-btn">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-style-02">Create a free account <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  With my image still part of it clipped:
https://ibb.co/ySpG5gK

Comment: @Jetz can you upload your background image [here](https://imgbb.com/)? This can give you temporary hosting for your image so we can work with that actual image that is causing the issue, to get you the best solution possible.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1T8GXp2 , P.S. i also added html code to the description

Comment: @Jetz see the adjustment. This should work well for you. If you're going to use `background-image: url('');` you have to set that on an existing class. `.background-property` was not anywhere in the markup.

Comment: @Jetz Also, I used `background-position: top;`

Comment: I did as you said, but then the bottom is cut off - https://ibb.co/31xGFmZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240769/discussion-between-jetz-and-kameron).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting `background-size: 100% 100%;`

```css
.background-property {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution does not help. The image becomes distorted